# GitLab CI/CD Components and project bots

Tags: gitlab, cicd

TL;DR

We finally just created a new bot at top group level which have access to both repository. So, yea, it is not possible to use project bots.

---

We have GitLab self-managed free version. Since version 16 there is a great feature as CI/CD Catalog.

Now, we have few projects that have their own project bots to do some automatic commits, etc. After we include some components from CI/CD Catalog there are some problems occured.

Firstly, GitLab documentation said that to use CI/CD Catalog a user must have permission for CI/CD Catalog project.

Secondly, project bots cannot be assigned to any other projects.

The conclusion is that when any project are using project bot to run some CI jobs there is no way to use jobs from CI/CD Catalog because the job owner (in this case project bot) has no access to CI/CD Catalog project. Am I right or we something missing and it is possible to include jobs from CI/CD catalog when projet bot is the trigger of job?

GitLab produce an error in pipeline:

```
 Unable to create pipeline 

    component <name_of_component> - project does not exist or you don't have sufficient permissions
```

There is no error when the job triggerer is "normal" user.

I tried to search some more info abut that in Google but there is still not much information about GitLab CI/CD components. And didn't saw similar problem. Maybe the only option for now is to use assecc token of some "real" user in GitLab instead project bot?

Comment: Do you have the same error with a group bot (who can access to your project and CI/CD catalog project)?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Our CI/CD Catalog project is in different group than project in wich I want to include those components. I suspect that the only way is to have bots on top level group or move CI/CD Catalog to group with project :/

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be possible currently, however I have used some workaround.
Simply start the pipeline by calling a trigger in your pipeline, in order to start the other pipeline https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/
and it'll work like a charm.

Comment: We finally just created a new bot at top group level which have access to both repository. So, yea, it is not possible to use project bots.